Correct Tailwind config Type when using a custom preset and Typescript
I have the following custom preset for tailwind with some of our base configuration:
/** @type {Omit<import('tailwindcss').Config, 'content'>} */

export default {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        primary: {
          25: "#F0F9F9",
          50: "#E1F4F3",
          100: "#C3EAE7",
          200: "#A4DFDA",
          300: "#86D5CF",
          400: "#68CAC3",
          500: "#4ABFB8",
          600: "#3AA69F",
          700: "#308882",
          800: "#256A65",
          900: "#1B4B48",
        }
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
};


And then we have this config file in one of our apps:
/** @type {Pick<import('tailwindcss').Config, 'content', 'presets'>} */
import sharedConfig from "@our_repo/tailwind-config";

export default {
  content: ["./src/app/**/*.tsx"],
  presets: [sharedConfig],
};


If I do something like:
console.log(tailwindConfig.theme.colors.primary["500"]) the correct color value is printed to the console but the ts compiler complains about "Property 'primary' does not exist on type 'DefaultColors'."
I was wondering if there is an elegant way to fix this without declaring a new type specifically for this preset.

Probably your path should be tailwindConfig.theme.extend.colors.primary["500"]

@HairyHandKerchief23 I don't think so because that according to the docs the configs are being merged into one. Also, extend does not exist in the path and also, as I said, the correct value is being printed into the console so this is the right path.

ah so the problem is pure typescript problem
